# How to implement theme option to change bootstrap 4 container from .container to .container-fluid

Tags: themes, options

Developing wordpress theme from scratch, I got some basics, but, as I start to make templates for changing the look of a page (like 1 or 2 or 3 columns, with or without sidebar...), an idea came to me that that it would be nice to give option in theme to easy change bootstraps 4 .container to .container-fluid.

Container div starts in header.php and ends in footer.php. How could I implement this option in theme?

Comment: And your question is exactly?

Comment: sorry i edited question, so, I would like to know how to implement that kind of option in theme. thank you

Comment: Okay, did you already check [the Customizer API doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/)? I recommend the complete Theme Handbook, this specific chapter should explain how to do it

Comment: nope, I did not, thank you very much, if I will have some solution I will post here :)

Comment: Ok, I see that we can create custom panel, section and control. So if I wan't to have new menu item in customizer I have to make custom panel? And panel won't show unless it has at least one section, and at least one control? Thank you

Comment: To be honest I'm not too familiar with it myself .. You should be able to add the section/field to an existing panel

Comment: yes, I was wrong, panel is not menu item, but section is "menu item", but it won't show unless i add setting and control I guess, and in this case it is custom control, I found working example here: https://infobest.ro/create-better-themes-using-wordpress-theme-customizer/

Answer (score 0):

Here is possible solution that works (theme name is "zoran"):

```
//1. Step (Create Customizer section, setting, control)

//In functions.php include or directly put code that goes something like this:



function zoran_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
$wp_customize->add_section( 'zoran_sekcija', array(
    'title'          => __( 'Zoran', 'zoran' ),
    'priority'       => 35,
) );
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'zoran_postavka', array(
    'default'        => 'container',
    'type' => 'theme_mod',
    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
) );

$wp_customize->add_control('zoran_control', array(
    'label'   => 'Container',
    'section' => 'zoran_sekcija',
    'settings'   => 'zoran_postavka',
    'type' => 'radio',
    'choices' => array(
        'container' => 'Fluid',
        'container-fluid' => 'Fixed', 
    ),
) );


}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'zoran_customize_register' );

 //2. Step (Create javascript to manipulate class container)

 //In functions.php include or type:

function zoran_customize_js()
{
?>
     <script>
         div = document.getElementsByClassName("container");
         div[0].classList.toggle(<?php echo "'" . get_theme_mod('zoran_postavka', 'container') . "'"; ?>);


     </script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'zoran_customize_js');
```

I think that's it. Please make suggestions for improvement.

[image: preview]